# Transforming content of HTML div to a script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change a the content of an html div into an javascript code. I have no idea if this is possible and how to achieve it. Concrete:

```
<div id="anything" class="pgn">1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 g6 3. Nc3 Bg7</div>
```

Should be transformed in:

```
<script>
    new PgnViewer({ 
    boardName: "anything",  
    pgnString: '1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 g6 3. Nc3 Bg7'
    }  
);  
</script>
```

Note that this should happen for all divs with class "pgn". The boardname should be the id of the div.

Thanks for help and tipps!

Comment: What is your script code supposed to be doing? Are you just wanting to take the contents/id of the DIV and turn it into a json data object? That can certainly be done.

Comment: This code is for an external script. pgn is a chess notation. This code will show up a board, which displays a chess game.

To be honest: I don't know the answer to your question... I just know, that I need to have the script code in my html file. But this is very unpractical to add in my cms editor. So I thought I could write something like that div code and change it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Is that alright?

```
$('.png').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text()
    var newObj = new PgnViewer({
        boardName: $(this).attr('id'),
        pngString: text
    })

    $('body').append('<script>' + JSON.stringify(newObj) + '</script>')
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. I see even this ") }) " in my text. There is something wrong with the js code.

Comment: Still the same... Maybe my idea to achieve this with javascript is just wrong?

Comment: What's the error? I've tried `$('body').append('<script>console.log("helllo");</script>')` and it works, so the idea is good. Maybe there's an error in the construction of the object